# Create views block that displays related content based on a text field value shared among these nodes?

Tags: 7, blocks, views

I'm building out a views block where it should show all the related content based on the shared field value of a text field. Currently you can show related content based on "taxonomy" terms, but I don't see an option to base it off of a text field value. My text field is called campaign and this is manually typed into each node. I'd like to show all the related items based on this text field, where would this be set in Views?